# AQuery upload image from local device to server

Tags: java, android, aquery

I would like to do that using https://code.google.com/p/android-query/wiki/AsyncAPI
Does this library have support for this purpose?

I'm a newbie in Android & Java and is hard to understand the api yet.

Answer (score 0):

```
public void async_post(){

//do a twiiter search with a http post

String url = "http://search.twitter.com/search.json";

Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<String, Object>();
params.put("q", "androidquery");

aq.ajax(url, params, JSONObject.class, new AjaxCallback<JSONObject>() {

    @Override
    public void callback(String url, JSONObject json, AjaxStatus status) {

        showResult(json);

    }
});
```

}

Comment: I'm not convinced about your answer, I didn't paid attention when I marked it.
For uploading this is the solution:
https://code.google.com/p/android-query/wiki/AsyncAPI#Http_POST_(Multipart)

Answer (score 0):

```
private void aync_multipart(){

    String url = "https://graph.facebook.com/me/photos";

    Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    params.put("message", "Message");

    //Simply put a byte[] to the params, AQuery will detect it and treat it as a multi-part post
    byte[] data = getImageData();
    params.put("source", data);

    //Alternatively, put a File or InputStream instead of byte[]
    //File file = getImageFile();           
    //params.put("source", file);

    AQuery aq = new AQuery(getApplicationContext());
    aq.auth(handle).ajax(url, params, JSONObject.class, this, "photoCb");
}
```

From: https://code.google.com/p/android-query/wiki/AsyncAPI#Http_POST_(Multipart)